# Lavarel 9 many to many relationship

Tags: php, datatables, relationship

I have three tables: Users, Videogames and videogames_users . How can I display the videogames selected by the users?
This is what I need to achieve (picture 1) but what I’m getting is this (picture 2)

Picture 1
[image: picture 1]

Picture 2

[image: Picture 2]

**Controller**

```
public function users()
{
    $videogamesBuilder = VideoGames::with(['plataforma', 'generos', 'categoria', 'numJugadores', 'users']);
    $users = DB::table(users)->select('user_id', 'nombre', 'email','rol_usuario')->get();
    $videogames = $videogamesBuilder->paginate(4)->withQueryString();
    return view('admin.videojuegos.users', [
    'videogames' => $videogames,
    'users' => $users,
]);
}
```

**Model**

```
class User extends User
{
   use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
   protected $table = 'users';
   protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
   protected $fillable = [ 'email', 'nombre', 'password', 'rol_usuario'];
   protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
   public const VALIDATE_RULES = [
    'email' => 'required',
    'nombre' => 'required|min:5',
    'password' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
    'rol_usuario' => 'required',
];
}
```

**Migration Videogame**

```
class CreateVideojuegosTable extends Migration
{
public function up()
{
     Schema::create('videogames', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->id('videogame_id');
     $table->string('titulo', 300);
     $table->text('subtitulo');
     $table->timestamps();
});
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('videogames');
}
}
```

**Migration Users**

```
return new class extends Migration
{

public function up()
{
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->id('user_id');
   $table->string('email')->unique();
   $table->string('nombre');
   $table->string('password');
   $table->string('rol_usuario');
   $table->rememberToken();
   $table->timestamps();
});
}

public function down()
{
   Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
};
```

**Migration Videogames selected by users**

```
return new class extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('videojuegos_tienen_usuarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('videogames_id')->constrained('videogames', 'videogames_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_id')->on('users');
        $table->primary(['videogames_id', 'user_id']);

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
   Schema::dropIfExists('videojuegos_tienen_usuarios');
}
};
```

**Sedeer**

```
class VideojuegosTienenUsuariosSeeder extends Seeder
{

public function run()
{
\DB::table('videojuegos_tienen_usuarios')->insert([
[
'videojgame_id' => 1,
'user_id' => 1,
'created_at' => now(),
'updated_at' => now(),
],
[
'videojgame_id' => 2,
'user_id' => 1,
'created_at' => now(),
'updated_at' => now(),
],
[
'videojgame_id' => 2,
'user_id' => 2,
'created_at' => now(),
'updated_at' => now(),
],
[
'videojgame_id' => 2,
'user_id' => 3,
'created_at' => now(),
'updated_at' => now(),
],
[
'videojgame_id' => 3,
'user_id' => 1,
'created_at' => now(),
'updated_at' => now(),
]
]);
}
}
```

**view**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nombre de usuario</th>
                <th>Email Usuario</th>
                <th>Rol del Usuario</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $user->user_id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->rol_usuario }}</td>
        @endforeach
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to implement a many-to-many relationship, please check: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Just follow the table naming structure and add this method to your User model:

```
public function videogames()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(VideoGame::class);
}
```

Afterwards you can query the videogames of an user in your view for each user like:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $user->user_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->nombre }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->rol_usuario }}</td>
        <td>
            @foreach($user->videogames as $game)
               {{ $game->titulo }},
            @endforeach
        </td>

@endforeach
```